# Проблема с выборкой данных из Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-database

Пытаюсь выбрать из таблицы даные по `id`. Но получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Object is no longer
>   valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?

Вот код запроса к БД

```
RealmQuery<Exercise> query = realm.where(Exercise.class);
for(Day d : dayList) {
    RealmResults<Exercise> results = query.equalTo("exercise_id",
            d.getExercise_id()).findAllAsync();
    exercises.addAll(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAllAsync()` ищет асинхронно и на следующей строке данные ещё не будут готовы.

Вам надо или сихронный запрос делать методом `findAll()` или оставить асинхронным, повесить слушатель на results и когда он вызовется по завершении запроса к БД добавлять данные